# Decimal conversion while in sed

Tags: sed

```
curl www.gatherproxy.com | sed '1,61d; 210,$d; /script/d' | sed 's/^\s*//; s/"//g; s/proxy_//gi; 0~1 a\\' | sed 's/.*\(country.*,\)\(ip:.*,\).*,\(port:.*,\).*,.*,\(status:.*,\).*,\(type:.*,\).*$/\1\2\3\4\5/i'
```

It output is like

```
COUNTRY:Singapore,IP:180.210.201.59,PORT:C39,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent,UID:null,
                                          ↑                               ↑
```

Firstly, I do not understand why `UID:null,` appears in my output when I have not included it in my code.

Second, I want to convert everything after `Port:` and before the next `,` to be displayed in decimal, **I don't know what format this is printing in**.

Output should be like

```
COUNTRY:Singapore,IP:180.210.201.59,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
                                          ↑
```

I want the port number to be displayed instead of what it is printing right now. **I don't know if 'c39' corresponds to '8080' here**. But hope you got the point.

Comment: post the final desired result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have updated the question a little bit, please check

Comment: Use non-greedy matches instead of greedy match. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed

Comment: there's no `8080` port within output returned by `curl www.gatherproxy.com`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, there's no port displayed in decimal format, that is the whole point. The port numbers are displayed in some different format. I want to convert them to decimal format

Comment: @KaushikNayak sed doesn't support non-greedy wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex solution using a proper tools (*grep* + *jq* + *awk*):

```
curl www.gatherproxy.com | grep -io '{"proxy_[^}]*}' \
 | jq -r '. | {COUNTRY:.PROXY_COUNTRY, IP:.PROXY_IP,PORT:.PROXY_PORT,STATUS:.PROXY_STATUS,TYPE:.PROXY_TYPE}' -c \
 | sed 's/["{}]//g' | awk -F, '{ p=substr($3,6); $3="PORT:" sprintf("%d",strtonum("0x" p)); }1' OFS=','
```

The output:

```
COUNTRY:Canada,IP:47.52.5.8,PORT:3128,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Spain,IP:86.109.100.80,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Indonesia,IP:36.66.38.186,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:China,IP:122.112.210.64,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Egypt,IP:41.33.173.130,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Brazil,IP:179.208.202.130,PORT:80,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:China,IP:121.42.154.207,PORT:3128,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Brazil,IP:179.178.34.129,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Brazil,IP:187.120.181.172,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Hong Kong,IP:137.74.5.69,PORT:3128,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Brazil,IP:189.107.28.64,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Brazil,IP:200.198.55.1,PORT:3128,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Brazil,IP:177.103.182.12,PORT:5000,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Germany,IP:62.214.70.116,PORT:3128,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Brazil,IP:189.40.191.95,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Malaysia,IP:161.139.20.49,PORT:8111,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Anonymous
COUNTRY:United States,IP:52.237.24.110,PORT:80,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Anonymous
COUNTRY:Hong Kong,IP:219.76.4.12,PORT:88,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Turkey,IP:88.255.150.226,PORT:8888,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Russia,IP:92.126.9.142,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Russia,IP:217.119.82.14,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Japan,IP:133.242.237.206,PORT:88,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Taiwan,IP:203.74.4.7,PORT:80,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Hong Kong,IP:219.76.4.72,PORT:88,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:France,IP:86.208.110.49,PORT:80,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Russia,IP:92.126.21.98,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Russia,IP:62.182.25.38,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Panama,IP:200.108.35.60,PORT:8087,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Hong Kong,IP:152.101.20.35,PORT:80,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Russia,IP:195.88.23.252,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Turkey,IP:91.93.132.138,PORT:3128,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Russia,IP:109.75.254.139,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Ukraine,IP:94.130.14.146,PORT:31288,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Anonymous
COUNTRY:Indonesia,IP:180.251.144.71,PORT:80,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Colombia,IP:181.143.213.202,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Russia,IP:176.62.77.212,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:United Kingdom,IP:88.99.149.188,PORT:31288,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Anonymous
COUNTRY:United States,IP:142.4.204.69,PORT:3128,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Germany,IP:148.251.133.60,PORT:3128,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Russia,IP:31.173.218.199,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Italy,IP:178.239.177.210,PORT:80,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Elite
COUNTRY:Russia,IP:95.220.218.24,PORT:8081,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Germany,IP:83.169.17.103,PORT:80,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Anonymous
COUNTRY:Malaysia,IP:221.133.44.142,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Anonymous
COUNTRY:India,IP:59.145.117.26,PORT:3128,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Bangladesh,IP:180.234.223.91,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Thailand,IP:183.88.41.150,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:China,IP:223.68.1.38,PORT:8000,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:Russia,IP:37.29.107.126,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
COUNTRY:United States,IP:144.217.248.180,PORT:8080,STATUS:OK,TYPE:Transparent
```

Comment: It does not convert the format of port numbers to decimal. The main point was not eliminating the `UID:null`. I could have done it with one more filter for `UID`, the main point of the question is to convert the port number to decimal

Comment: well, you wrote *I don't know if 'c39' corresponds to '8080'* - and it does not correspond, `C39` is `3129`

Comment: Which format are port numbers written in here?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut, enjoy my update

Comment: Thanks for your precious time doing my problem. I simply removed the new-line characters from your code before running it as a one liner in my terminal. The one-liner of your code I have is `curl www.gatherproxy.com | grep -io '{"proxy_[^}]*}' | jq -r '. |{COUNTRY:.PROXY_COUNTRY,IP:.PROXY_IP,PORT:.PROXY_PORT,STATU‌​S:.PROXY_STATUS,TYPE‌​:.PROXY_TYPE}' -c | sed 's/["{}]//g' | | awk -F, '{ p=substr($3,6); $3="PORT:" sprintf("%d",strtonum("0x" p)); }1' OFS=','` but this gives an error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token |'`

Comment: check my update, should work (there was redundant `| |`)

Comment: This is my file with your code https://pastebin.com/j16ZNNr7 and this is the output of running that file https://pastebin.com/EhDV99Ff . Is there problem with my machine only ?

Comment: see my next update: do it in 2 steps. But, it seems, that the content of `www.gatherproxy.com` changes dynamically and there are no crucial items within

Comment: Turns out, `jq` was not installed, I assumed `jq` was already installed. After removing new-line characters from your code, it worked. Thank you so much for your time. It was my mistake at last. Also I'm updating your answer to remove new-line characters which were the reason the code was not running even after installing `jq`. Hope it helps other people copying your code for testing and hope you don't mind the edit. Thank you so much again....

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut, check my last update

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help, time and patience.

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut, you're welcome